# Bundle chunks are not loading in iPhone for stencil theme in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using Chiara theme based on stencil in bigcommerce and here is the link of it :

https://bg-test.mybigcommerce.com

I have done few customizations and its working properly in desktops and andriod devices but some how its giving following error in iPhone on browser console :

```
[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored. (x2)
[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (theme-bundle.main.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (theme-bundle.chunk.4.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (theme-bundle.chunk.2.js.map, line 0)
```

If you go to following url : https://bg-test.mybigcommerce.com/graco-extend2fit-convertible-car-seat/

The datepicker should work but its not working on iPhone and due to the above errors

I have tried to remove the devtool: 'source-map' from webpack but its the same error on iPhone

Please not that it is working in desktop safari but it is not working on iphone on safari, chrome both

Comment: Are you using a particular plugin for the datepicker calendar?

Comment: Yeah I am using fdatepicker or foundation datepicker

Comment: I have switched the datepicker from foundation to bootstrap datepicker and its working now on iPhone as well,

However above errors still appears in console but everything seems working now.